# An Italian book suitable for a beginner

Tags: vocabulary, resources

I have been learning Italian for several months now and I am looking for a book --- the genre is not important --- suitable for someone with a rather basic understanding of the language. It need not be a book; any substantial text that keeps the language simple will do. Any recommendations?

**EDIT** (June 21st 2015). Several people from this community have offered helpful suggestions in the form of answers and comments. Unfortunately, I can only accept a single answer and I am not sure whether it is fair to do so as all the answers are of sufficient quality and each of them deserves to be accepted.

Below is a compiled list of suggestions; it is essentially the union of the suggestions in the answers to this question.

- *Le avventure di Pinocchio* by Carlo Collodi;
- *Cuore* by Edmondo De Amicis ([text](http://www.liberliber.it/online/autori/autori-d/edmondo-de-amicis/cuore/); [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F3JcSATErbQ));
- several books by Emilio Salgari (especially the [Malaysia cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emilio_Salgari#Pirates_of_Malaysia_.28Sandokan.29));
- children's literature in general;
- *La solitudine dei numeri primi* by Paolo Giordano;
- lyrics of various [pop songs](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Festival_di_Sanremo_2015#Campioni) or, for something older and classier, songs by *cantautori* like De André ([lyircs 1](http://www.testimania.com/testi/testi_fabrizio_de_andre_1059/testi_in_direzione_ostinata_e_contraria_17307/testo_via_del_campo_200197.html); [lyrics 2](http://www.testimania.com/testi/testi_fabrizio_de_andre_1059/testi_in_direzione_ostinata_e_contraria_17307/testo_volta_la_carta_200231.html)) and De Gregori ([sample lyrics](http://www.angolotesti.it/F/testi_canzoni_francesco_de_gregori_125/testo_canzone_generale_1939005.html)); beyond the *cantautori* there are also folk and political singers-songwriters of which [Fausto Amodei](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fausto_Amodei) is an example;
- a particular song, [Meno male che](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrOJpHL8Yfo).

Comment: I find this question very interesting!

Comment: Songs have already been suggested. I have always used and still use songs for my English, but I am very careful with the choice: I generally find better English in older songs.
I would like to suggest one particular song in Italian, by an unknown cantautore, which was written and accepted at the Sanremo Academy, and then voted among the best, but never got to the famous festival.
The name of the song is "Menomale Che" and if you put it in Google, followed by "Francesca", you can listen to it. And if you click "Mostra Altro" you can read the full text.
As it's good Italian (not the rule today,

Comment: @alsa who is the song sung by? I gather it is not by Francesca Salcioli?

Comment: @ blazs. Sorry, I have just seen your question. Yes, it is sung by my daughter Francesca (as you probably can still see below under "Answers"). If you liked it, you might want try another one: "Mare d'Inverno". I can send it to you (3900 KB) if you give me your e-mail adress.

Comment: I would suggest you to take a look at app store's library for this. I've found lots of good books in there to dive in. Enjoy!

Answer (score 15):

I suggest you to read books that you already read in your own language. This way is simpler to follow the story. I used this method to learn English and it helped me a lot.

In alternative, for a easy reading, you could choose Italian juvenile fiction, who has a simple language. Some example:

- *Le avventure di Pinocchio* by Carlo Collodi
- *Cuore* by Edmondo de Amicis
- Emilio Salgari, a lot of books

They are considered books for youths, but I think they are interesting for everyone. Further you can learn Italian language but also something about Italian culture.

Comment: @blazs you can download it (with other books of public domain) from liberliber.it 

http://www.liberliber.it/online/autori/autori-d/edmondo-de-amicis/cuore/

Comment: It should be noted that these are rather old (and old-fashioned) books.

Comment: *[Cuore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F3JcSATErbQ)* is also available as a six-part mini-series, which could be useful ancillary material to your reading.

Comment: PS: Pinocchio is awesome! One of the best books I have readed in italian.

Answer (score 8):

I strongly recommend anything by Gianni Rodari.

"Favole al telefono" is truly a gem.
Easy to read, good and small stories, perfect to learn and practice written Italian.

> Il protagonista è il ragionier Bianchi, di Varese, rappresentante
>   farmaceutico in giro per l'Italia condannato ad un settimanale
>   pendolarismo, interrotto soltanto la domenica. Ogni sera, alle nove in
>   punto, raccontava una favola al telefono alla figlioletta che non
>   riusciva a dormire. Le storie toccavano tanto il cuore, che le
>   centraliniste interrompevano il loro lavoro per ascoltarle.

Source:
https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favole_al_telefono

Answer (score 6):

If you prefer to read more recent literature which is not intended for youths, I can tell you that the first book I read in Italian was *La solitudine dei numeri primi* by Paolo Giordano and I found it quite easy to understand. It may help if you have a translation to your own language with you: if you find something difficult to understand you can have a look to the translation. This is a method I have used whenever I started with a foreign language.

Answer (score 6):

Since you say *It need not be a book; any substantial text that keeps the language simple will do*; have you tried **song texts**?

(Sadly) the texts of most of today's [pop songs](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Festival_di_Sanremo_2015#Campioni) are quite simple from a linguistic point of view. For something older and classier you can listen for instance to *cantautori* like [De](http://www.testimania.com/testi/testi_fabrizio_de_andre_1059/testi_in_direzione_ostinata_e_contraria_17307/testo_via_del_campo_200197.html) [André](http://www.testimania.com/testi/testi_fabrizio_de_andre_1059/testi_in_direzione_ostinata_e_contraria_17307/testo_volta_la_carta_200231.html) or [De Gregori](http://www.angolotesti.it/F/testi_canzoni_francesco_de_gregori_125/testo_canzone_generale_1939005.html). Some of their texts, such as the linked ones, need very little grammar to be understood, and I believe that the words are easy to discern (with the song text available).

Comment: @blazs: A word of caution about De Gregori: his texts may _seem_ not to make much sense, at times. Their style is often quite poetic. Anyways, these are two giants, among the [_cantautori_](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantautore), but then there are _many_ others. I don't want to list any of them, because everyone has his favorites, and the list would quickly get exceedingly long. Google is your friend.

Comment: Beyond the _cantautori_ there are also _folk_ and _political_ singers-songwriters, although they are almost forgotten nowadays. An example that comes to my mind of someone with a very clear (albeit often quick) pronunciation is [Fausto Amodei](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fausto_Amodei). Left wing, though, so not for everyone.

Comment: @FredericoPoloni, I have not; thanks for the suggestion; I will give it a try.

Comment: @WalterTross, thanks for pointing this out; the only _cantautori_ I am familiar with are Lucio Battisti and Lucio Dalla.

Comment: @blazs: does Battisti even qualify? I thought he didn't write his own lyrics.

Comment: @TobiaTesan: My bad. (Wikipedia says that he was, among other things, a cantautore, so I listed him.)

Comment: If we are talking about Italian songwriters, I suggest you also Francesco Guccini , Roberto Vecchioni and Enrico Ruggeri . They have a great use of language and their songs use a uncommon wide variety of words.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a beginner too (Duolinguo has helped a lot). I found 2 books by Cinzia Medaglia that were good for starters. The stories & characters are a bit rudimentary, but there's a lot of dialog and action (not just description). There is some slang, which I wouldn't dare use myself, though. Pinocchio was hard! Now I'm reading the Italian translation of Harry Potter--not Italian literature, but I'm not ready for D'Annunzio (I tried & it took me 1 hr per paragraph....). Song lyrics have helped too -Adriano Celentano, Zucchero. Hope this helps.

Comment: Skip D'Annunzio altogether. The 20th century has way, way better, from Pirandello to Eco, from Palazzeschi to Gadda (not very beginner-friendly), Calvino (more like it) and many more.

Comment: Honestly I would need to be coerced to read D'Annunzio. I understand his poetry has its qualities, but he always seemed to me to be a very overrated author.

Answer (score 1):

A book that I enjoyed using as a beginner is [The Berlitz Self-Teacher - Italian](https://books.google.ca/books?id=rOuX_ng0bCAC&lpg=PA317&ots=GOtHp_phDr&dq=berlitz%20self%20teacher%20italian&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=berlitz%20self%20teacher%20italian&f=false).

- it has a slow, gradual approach.
- every line of text is presented in 3 parts: Italian, how to pronounce the Italian (Doh-VEH eel seen-YOHR...), and its English translation (I like this design).
- it was written in 1950. It uses the formal 'Lei' more often than in modern Italian. In addition, a few words here and there have fallen out of fashion, but that's not a big deal.
- it's very much oriented towards conversational Italian.
- it has minimal amounts of formal grammar.

Comment: I believe the OP was asking about a reading book they could tackle with a basic knowledge of Italian, not a book to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several graded reading series wiht many interesting books:

- [Black Cat Graded Readers](http://www.blackcat-cideb.com/en/catalogue/italian/) (levels from A2 to C1 with and without Audio CD): Here the [Catalogue in pdf](http://www.blackcat-cideb.com/uploads/2017/06/ZZITA17E_Catalogo_Italiano_SC.pdf).
- [Bravi Lettori](https://www.loescher.it/dettagliocatalogo/o_30260/bravi-lettori#configurazione) (levels from A2 to B1 with and without Audio CD)
- [Primiracconti Edilingua](http://www.edilingua.it/it-it/Prodotti.aspx?ElementID=ca6410a9-f0dd-4308-90ce-405b9560565a&Action=First) (levels from A1 to C2 with and without Audio CD)
- [Il piacere della lettura](http://www.guerra-edizioni.com/books/index.cfm?node=0,1,13,122) (levels from A2 to C1 with and without Audio CD)
- [LETTURE GRADUATE PER STRANIERI](http://www.guerra-edizioni.com/books/index.cfm?node=0,1,13,123) (levels from A2 to C1 with and without Audio CD)
- [ELI Graded Readers in Italian](http://www.eligradedreaders.com/en/result-filtrer-page/italiano/?custom_f_3[0]=325f41646f6c657363656e7469&custom_f_3[1]=335f47696f76616e69206164756c7469&custom_f_4[0]=315f4131&custom_f_4[1]=325f4132&custom_f_4[2]=335f4231) (levels from A1 to B1 with and without Audio CD)