# Easy Italian literature

Tags: resources

When I was learning French, I used my several months of knowledge to read *L’Étranger* by Albert Camus. What easy literature is there to read in Italian? Some examples in French are *Le Petit Prince*, *Le Petit Nicholas*, and *L’Étranger*. I’m not looking for children books, but fairly easy literature.

Comment: Not sure whether it is an actual duplicate, but you can find some pointers in [this question](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5634/an-italian-book-suitable-for-a-beginner).

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: Just to be clear: you are specifically looking for Italian literature (as in, written by Italian authors) and not for literature whose Italian translation is easy, correct?

Comment: @Easymode44 è corretto!

Answer (score 5):

These are some Italian books recommended by the Official Language Schools of Catalonia to students who have an A1 level and are learning to acquire an A2 level:

- Andrea Camilleri: *La relazione*.
- Rossana Campo: *Il matrimonio di Maria*.
- Chiara Sasso: *Riace, terra di accoglienza*.
- Chiara Gamberale: *Per dieci minuti*.
- Luigi Garlando: *Per questo mi chiamo Giovanni*.
- Niccolò Ammaniti: *Io e te*.
- Fabio Volo: *Quando tutto inizia*.
- Natalia Ginzburg: *La strada che va in città*.
- Stefano Benni: *Margherita Dolcevita*.
- Italo Calvino: *Marcovaldo*.
- Massimo Carlotto: *Niente, più niente al mondo*.
- Gianrico Carofiglio: *Testimone inconsapevole*.
- Geppi Cucciari: *Meglio donna che male accompagnata*.
- Natalia Ginzburg: *Caro Michele*.
- Amara Lakhous: *Scontro di civiltà per un ascensore a piazza Vittorio*.
- Dacia Maraini: *Dolce per sé*.
- Paola Mastrocola: *Facebook in the rain*.
- Francesco Piccolo: *Momenti di trascurabile infelicità*.
- Gianni Rodari: *C'era due volte il barone Lamberto*.
- Fabio Volo: *Un giorno in più*.

Comment: If by any strange accident Gamberale, Lakhous and Volo (no less than two titles!) slipped away from the list, I don't think that the average level would drop dramatically.

Comment: @DaG: Are you suggesting to remove these authors from the list? In fact I read a book by Volo some years ago and I didn't like it at all.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to censor that list. I'm just saying that I wouldn't especially recommend those authors. To be more positive, I highly recommend other of them, especially Calvino, Ginzburg, Rodari, Benni.

Comment: @DaG: Adesso me n'accorgo che non ho letto nessun libro di Fabio Volo. Il libro che avevo in mente quando ho scritto quel altro commento in realtà è di Sandro Veronesi: non so perché ho avuto questa confusione.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, *Il piccolo principe* and *Lo straniero* are just as good in Italian as in French - perhaps, a bit less difficult, as is usual with translated texts. Also, junk literature is much easier (and often more entertaining) for a beginner than classical texts - I mean detective novels, love stories, fantasy, etc. This might be hard to find abroad, but if you are in Italy or Switzerland, you will have a great choice in any bookstore.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd suggest junk stuff or translated texts to someone who studied French by reading Camus, but why not.

Comment: @DaG The advantage of the junk stuff is that it is available in great abundance. Honestly, my French and German began to progress really quickly once I stopped being snobbish and settled for junk - which is admittedly, the kind of literature that I wouldn't read in a language that I know well.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it's really super easy but you may want to try *Le città invisibili* written by Italo Calvino. It describes imaginary cities and since there is no ultra twisted plot may be ok to understand, even if sometimes some old words are used.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: I've read both *Marcovaldo* and *Le città invisibili*. *Le città invisibili* is certainly a masterpiece, but I think it could be a bit hard to understand to someone who has studied Italian for not many time. If such an Italian student would like to read something by Calvino, I believe *Marcovaldo* would be easier to understand.